# how to run robot framework(autoit) test in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, windows-7-x64, autoit, robotframework

I have a robot file, written with autoit library. Using it for testing a 3rd party software installation in Windows 7.

If I run this robot file, a pop-up window will appear, from here I need to proceed with next steps of software installation. (Please NOTE : I know that , I can do silent installation here. But my job  is to validate the pop-up window :( )

Now the problem is :

If I run this robot file from windows command prompt, using "pybot test.robot" command. its working as expected. But when I integrate this with jenkins, the pop-up window NOT appearing. I am getting the below error:

```
[Job to run RFW test] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson8861333201655586740.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Job to run RFW test>pybot Software_install_testsuite.robot 
==============================================================================
Software install testsuite                                                      
==============================================================================

TESTCASE1 : ID 1234                                                   | FAIL |
**AutoItError: timeout on wait for activate window**
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried with "xshell", "power shell" and "Windows batch command" in ADD BUILD STEP in jenkins. But still I am seeing the same error.

From last two weeks I am trying to fix this. Any help on this is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to watch the desktop that jenkins is attached to, to see whether the installation dialog is popping up? The error message implies that the dialog never shows up.

Comment: @BryanOakley. I am running this jenkins job from the server itself. I mean both Jenkins server and test setup desktop is same. I am unable to see the pop-ip window in this machine.  I have tried by configuring abother windows machine as slave. But same issue.

Comment: If you can't see the window pop up, then maybe neither can the test. Perhaps the first step is to figure out how to see the popup dialog while the test is running. _then_ worry about how to automate it.

Comment: @BryanOakley.. Actually as I mentioned in my question itself, I am getting this pop-up window when I run this robot file (Manually) using "pybot test.robot" from windows command prompt. I am NOT getting pop-up window only when I run this script through jenkins. I am looking for help to figure out this issue.

Comment: ok, my apologies. I didn't read the question close enough. I thought the problem was with using robot to automate the dialog. Now I see that the real problem is that the dialog doesn't appear. You might want to check whatever logs might be generated by the test and/or by the installer itself.

Comment: Is your jenkins process running as a service? It can't be run as a service if it opens up a window.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for your comment. Yes my jenkins slave  process is running as service. I found some option (interact with shell) if we right click on service. I am trying to use this option. Will let you know if its successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install vnc (e.g. ultravnc), run jenkins slave within this vnc session (don't use RDP connection), and then try to trigger test from jenkins.